# Smarter way to generate a matrix of zeros and ones in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, nodes, graph-theory

I would like to generate all the possible adjacency matrices (zero diagonale) of an undirected graph of `n` nodes.

For example, with no relabeling for `n=3` we get 2<sup>3(3-1)/2</sup> = 8 possible network configurations (or adjacency matrices).

One solution that works for `n = 3` (and which I think is quite stupid) would be the following:

```
n = 3;
A = [];
for k = 0:1
    for j = 0:1
        for i = 0:1
            m = [0 , i , j ; i , 0 , k ; j , k , 0 ];
            A = [A, m];
        end
    end
end
```

Also I though of the following which seems to be faster but something is wrong with my indexing since 2 matrices are missing:

```
n = 3
C = [];
E = [];

A = zeros(n);

for i = 1:n
    for j = i+1:n
        A(i,j) = 1;
        A(j,i) = 1;
        C = [C,A];
    end
end

B = ones(n);
B = B- diag(diag(ones(n)));
for i = 1:n
    for j = i+1:n
        B(i,j) = 0;
        B(j,i) = 0;
        E = [E,B];
    end
end

D = [C,E]
```

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: There are several problems like this over at Cody

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would definitely generate the off-diagonal elements of the adjacency matrices with binary encoding:

```
n = 4;  %// number of nodes
m = n*(n-1)/2;
offdiags = dec2bin(0:2^m-1,m)-48; %//every 2^m-1 possible configurations
```

If you have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox, then [`squareform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html) will easily create the matrices for you, one by one:

```
%// this is basically a for loop
tmpcell = arrayfun(@(k) squareform(offdiags(k,:)),1:size(offdiags,1),...
                 'uniformoutput',false);
A = cat(2,tmpcell{:}); %// concatenate the matrices in tmpcell
```

Although I'd consider concatenating along dimension `3`, then you can see each matrix individually and conveniently.

Alternatively, you can do the array synthesis yourself in a vectorized way, it's probably even quicker (at the cost of more memory):

```
A = zeros(n,n,2^m);
%// lazy person's indexing scheme:
[ind_i,ind_j,ind_k] = meshgrid(1:n,1:n,1:2^m);
A(ind_i>ind_j) = offdiags.'; %'// watch out for the transpose

%// copy to upper diagonal:
A = A + permute(A,[2 1 3]);  %// n x n x 2^m matrix

%// reshape to n*[] matrix if you wish
A = reshape(A,n,[]);         %// n x (n*2^m) matrix
```

Comment: Fantastic ! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello, is there a way to delete some of the matrices from the list generated? for n=6 I get 32768 but in my model all entries in every matrix the submatrices A(1:2,1:2,i) and A(3:6,3:6,i) have only zero entries. I tried the direct way of generating the matrices the way u suggested then setting to zero the entries of the mentionned sub-matrices. Then I search for identical matrix and am trying to find a way to delete the repeated matrices which are many thousands (ideally i would like to take the "intersection" of the generated matrices). thank u very much

Comment: @Sha it's probably simplest and most efficient if you don't create those matrices in the first place. I mean you should work with `offdiags`. Find those elements which should be 0 (for instance, block `A(1:2,1:2,i)` refers to the element `A(1,2,i)` which comes from `offdiags(1)`, `A(3,4:6,i)` comes from `offdiags(k:k+2)` where `k=(n-1)+(n-2)+1`, etc.). First zero out these columns in `offdiags`, then create `A` from `unique(offdiags,'rows')` which will select the unique configurations for you. Let me know whether this is clear.

Comment: @Sha sorry, I of course meant `offdiags(:,k:k+2)` etc. in my previous comment, so you need to consider full columns of `offdiags`.